# tab object is undefined in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am adding a simple listener to a tab that shows the page action in a chrome extension, but each time, `tab.id` is undefined. This script runs in a background page:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener
(
    function(tab)
    {

        chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);

    }
);
```

Each time, I get the error message that tab.id is undefined. Why is this happening? I have tabs in my permissions file:

```
"permissions":
    [
        "tabs"
    ]
```

The weirder part is that it works fine in the onCreated version when I add a listener, but the two functions are exactly the same:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener
(
    function(tab)
    {
            chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);
            concole.log("added onCreated listener");
    }
);
```

That works fine. What could be causing this?

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `tabs` permission for something like this. (Just so that you know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documenation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) for `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`:

> The callback parameter should specify a function that looks like this:

```
function(integer tabId, object changeInfo, Tab tab) {...};
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. +1